# How to hidden the "MapTypeControlStyle" control on Google-Maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, hidden

This is my code:

```
var myOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,position:google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
```

I see the doc, but I can't find the 'hidden' Property

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
disableDefaultUI: true
```

to your mapOptions.